# takhion-esque track frame identification!

Tags: identify-this-bike, track-racing

I thinking on buying this very lightweight track frame that is very similar in looks to those beautiful takhion pursuit frames from the urss 80's. I was told that brazilian cycling federation bought four of those frames in the late 90's for competing at a Pan Am and that's it, no more relevant info. The guy who holds the frame believed for some mysterious idea that this was a colnago frame and to me it makes absolute no sense since i've never heard of italian frames with similar geometry. My guess is south american, but I don't believe the italian threaded bb would match.

It is a 26.8mm seatpost and i could not find anything stamped on the dropouts neither on the bottom bracket or fork. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This bike is what appears to be an 80's pursuit frame. The closest I can come is a Schroder pursuit frame, however the butting at the seat stays is something I have never seen before, almost looks like there was a badge or something of that sort there. I have ever seen that. I would say 0% chance its a Takhion frame though. There are thousands of images of those, and not one has that butting.